# The import org.apache cannot be resolved VS code with extension pack, although pom seems ok

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, plugins, vscode-extensions

I am writing a maven plugin using extension pack for vs code.
Since short, vscode (or some extension) exposes a warning on

```
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;
```

namely

```
The import org.apache cannot be resolved
```

Strange enough, compilation on the console works fine,
so the pom is ok, also I found the requested class in folder `~/.m2`, so what is the problem?
What I am wondering is, that it has problem already at the prefix `org.apache`
and it fails with other imports with that prefix also.

I am not so much into the extensions.. maybe some update introducing a bug??

Comment: How do you compile in the console? What's wrong with using Java extensions? In addition, can you show your project structure, dependency management and other information?

Comment: @JialeDu: as unexpected as the problem arose, it disappeared again. 
Thank you for thinking about it.

Comment: Good to know the issue has been resolved, please consider writing an answer for it or closing the thread.

Answer (score 0):

I feel a bit ashame to present this as an answer,
but the problem disappeared as it arose: unexpected
and without any intended action of my side... maybe some update? I dont know.